# addition of two dataframes using the same timestamps

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

So I have two data frames.
Energy:

```
                       Affluent  Adversity  Affluent  Comfortable  Adversity  \
Time                                                                         
2019-01-01 01:00:00     0.254      0.244     0.155        0.215      0.274   
2019-01-01 02:00:00     0.346      0.154     0.083        0.246      0.046   
2019-01-01 03:00:00     0.309      0.116     0.085        0.220      0.139   
2019-01-01 04:00:00     0.302      0.158     0.083        0.226      0.186   
2019-01-01 05:00:00     0.181      0.171     0.096        0.246      0.051   
...                       ...        ...       ...          ...        ...   
2019-12-31 20:00:00     1.102      0.263     2.157        0.209      2.856   
2019-12-31 21:00:00     0.712      0.269     1.409        0.212      0.497   
2019-12-31 22:00:00     0.398      0.274     0.073        0.277      0.199   
2019-12-31 23:00:00     0.449      0.452     0.072        0.252      0.183   
2020-01-01 00:00:00     0.466      0.291     0.110        0.203      0.117
```

loadshift:

```
Time       load_difference
2019-01-01 01:00:00 0.10
2019-01-01 02:00:00 0.10
2019-01-01 03:00:00 0.15
2019-01-01 04:00:00 0.10
2019-01-01 05:00:00 0.10
... ...
2019-12-31 20:00:00 -0.10
2019-12-31 21:00:00 0.10
2019-12-31 22:00:00 0.15
2019-12-31 23:00:00 0.10
2020-01-01 00:00:00 -0.10
```

all I want to do is add the load difference to the df1 so for example the first affluent house at 1 am would change to 0.345. I have been able to use concat to multiply in my other models but somehow really struggling with this.

Expected output(but for all 8760 hours):

```
                  Affluent  Adversity  Affluent  Comfortable Adversity  \
Time
2019-01-01 01:00:00     0.354      0.344     0.255        0.315      0.374
2019-01-01 02:00:00     0.446      0.254     0.183        0.446      0.146
2019-01-01 03:00:00     0.409      0.216     0.185        0.320      0.239
2019-01-01 04:00:00     0.402      0.258     0.183        0.326      0.286
2019-01-01 05:00:00     0.281      0.271     0.196        0.346      0.151
```

I have tried: `Energy.add(loadshift, fill_value=0)`
but I get

`Concatenation operation is not implemented for NumPy arrays, use np.concatenate() instead. Please do not rely on this error; it may not be given on all Python implementations.`

also tried:

```
df_merged = pd.concat([Energy,loadshift], ignore_index=True, sort=False)
df_merged =Energy.append(loadshift)
```

this prints:

```
InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

How do I please go about to fixing these errors. Thanks

Comment: if you join the two dataframes you should get a dataframe with an extra column for load_difference, then just add the two columns to get a new Adversity column. If the indexes are the same you my just be able to do: Energy.Adversity += LoadShift.load_shift.

Comment: @Naveed hi thanks so much for your time, updating the original columns comes up with ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Comment: @Naveed yep done that and it now says ValueError: Shape of passed values is (8760, 3188), indices imply (8760, 100)

Comment: df2 has 2 columns but does that matter when df3 now has 8760 rows and 100 columns just like energy(df) so should just update it like by like? both have time set as index too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246982/discussion-between-telleryl-and-naveed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is one way to do it, which is to make use of add and then update

```
#to add two DF, both should have same number of columns
# so, we duplicate single column in loadshift(DF2) into as many columns as we #have in the energy df (DF), minus the datetime column.

#next we concat to add the datetime column to have a new df (DF3) that #matches the columns count with the energy (df) DF

df3=pd.concat([df2.iloc[:,0],
               pd.concat(
                   [df2.iloc[:,1]]*(len(df.columns)-1), axis=1
               )]
              , axis=1 )
#update column names
df3.columns = df.columns

# add DF and DF3 values and then update the original energy (df ) columns
df.update(df.iloc[:,1:].add(df3.iloc[:,1:]))

df
```

```
    Time    Affluent    Adversity   Affluent.1  Comfortable     Adversity.1
0   2019-01-01 01:00:00     0.354   0.344   0.255   0.315   0.374
1   2019-01-01 02:00:00     0.446   0.254   0.183   0.346   0.146
2   2019-01-01 03:00:00     0.459   0.266   0.235   0.370   0.289
3   2019-01-01 04:00:00     0.402   0.258   0.183   0.326   0.286
4   2019-01-01 05:00:00     0.281   0.271   0.196   0.346   0.151
5   2019-12-31 20:00:00     1.002   0.163   2.057   0.109   2.756
6   2019-12-31 21:00:00     0.812   0.369   1.509   0.312   0.597
7   2019-12-31 22:00:00     0.548   0.424   0.223   0.427   0.349
8   2019-12-31 23:00:00     0.549   0.552   0.172   0.352   0.283
9   2020-01-01 00:00:00     0.366   0.191   0.010   0.103   0.017
```

Comment: I don't use pandas so excuse my question if it's dumb but why can't we simply do `df["Affluent"] += df2["load_difference"]`?

Comment: load_difference has a single column, is getting added to all the columns in the energy, as I understood the question

Comment: Ah yes, my bad. Then it could be interesting to benchmark your solution against `for key in (key in df.keys() if key != "Time"): df[key] += df2["load_difference"]`.

Comment: @Guimoute, for loops are very slow when compared to the a vector solution

Comment: True but here we would only be looping to select the column, not looping the calculations. Fair enough!